# fixing odd geometry

Tags: mesh, modifiers, import, bmesh

I am dealing with geometry imported from a (very problematic) source and it is often such that I just want to keep the *outer volume* of a weird mesh. Here an example of something that is almost (but not quite) a box:

[image: a viewport render of weird stuff]

However, if you look at the corresponding mesh, it's a mess:

[image]

...because there are multiple faces inside (and even overlapping with the outer faces). Now, I don't care too much about the details - I just need to render this for a project - but rendering this leads to a lot of artifacts from Z-fighting from competing surfaces, and it ends up looking horrible in cycles compared to the trivial viewport render which is OK.

I am trying to find a way to deal with that, and one modifier that helped was "Solidify" - but it also changes the boundaries of the geometry itself. Solidify with zero skin size also doesn't help. The only other modifier that helped is remesh, but that's a bloody mess because there are slightly jagged edges unless I use the tiniest (and toughest, CPU-wise) voxel sizes. I would like to avoid that as it sounds a bit too much like brute force for a problem of removing mistakes in the "inner volume" of a mesh somehow...

I am now actually wondering if I cannot achieve something like the cleanup of the inner parts of this geometry via a python bmesh script or so. Would you have suggestions? If you want to look at the mess, here it is:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/a6tkyqwo7j0ucmd/geoToFix.blend?dl=0

Any hint or suggestion would be appreciated! I am not very experienced in bmesh manipulations. I hope this isn't too stupid of a question...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I managed to solve this by really selecting the vertices that I wanted manually and to offset them, so that the rendering artifacts (z-fighting) disappeared. The geometry itself is a gigantic mess, but hey, I'm only after a reasonable render, so I'm happy :-D

If anyone knows of more civilized solutions, I would still love to hear them, as manually editing this is a bit annoying :-)